# How to change all variables of a big dataset into ordinal factors that have different sets of orders for the levels of each one of them?

Tags: r, factors, levels, ordinal

I have this dataframe with it structure (let's imagine it very big)

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:5, 
                y = 2:6, 
                z = letters[6:10], 
                m =10:14, 
                n = 15:19,
                o = 20:24 )

str(df)
```

and I wish to convert all these variables **x, y, z, m, n *and* o** into ordinal factors with a simple function so that each one of them has its own order of levels as follows :

x : 5 < 4 < 3 < 2 < 1

y : 6 < 5 < 4 < 3 < 2

z : f < g < h < i < j

m : 10 > 11 > 12 > 13 > 14

n : 15 > 16 > 17 > 18 > 19

o : 20 < 21 < 22 < 23 < 24

Comment: How do you know which direction the factors are supposed to be ordered in? (x, y, m, and n are all in reverse order but o is not)

Comment: because the dataframe I have they are coded in a similar way that 5 is worse than 4 and 4 is worse than 3 and so on. And there are other variables that are coded in a way that 20 is worse than 21 and 21 is worse than 22 and so on (the numbers are just to make it clear what I am facing as a problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```r
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {
  if(is.numeric(x)) ordered(x, rev(sort(unique(x))))
  else ordered(x)
})
```

Resulting in

```
df
#>   x y z  m  n
#> 1 1 2 f 10 15
#> 2 2 3 g 11 16
#> 3 3 4 h 12 17
#> 4 4 5 i 13 18
#> 5 5 6 j 14 19

df$x
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> Levels: 5 < 4 < 3 < 2 < 1

df$y
#> [1] 2 3 4 5 6
#> Levels: 6 < 5 < 4 < 3 < 2

df$z
#> [1] f g h i j
#> Levels: f < g < h < i < j

df$m
#> [1] 10 11 12 13 14
#> Levels: 14 < 13 < 12 < 11 < 10

df$n
#> [1] 15 16 17 18 19
#> Levels: 19 < 18 < 17 < 16 < 15
```

Note that the levels in an ordered factor are always printed smallest to largest, so the desired levels you show in the last two columns are not valid for ordered factors in R (though the above is a direct equivalent)

---

**EDIT**

If you have different rules for each column, then you need to handle them separately:

```r
df[1:5] <- lapply(df[1:5], function(x) {
  if(is.numeric(x)) ordered(x, rev(sort(unique(x))))
  else ordered(x)
})

df$o <- ordered(df$o)

df$o
#> [1] 20 21 22 23 24
#> Levels: 20 < 21 < 22 < 23 < 24
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: In case I have a numeric variable that I wish to keep its levels on the same order. How can we modify the function you proposed to handle that ? thanks

Comment: @Anas116 a numeric variable doesn't _have_ levels. Do you mean an existing ordered factor, or do you mean a numeric variable that you wish not to convert to factor?

Comment: sorry I meant a numeric variable that I wish to convert it into an ordered factor as in variable o that I added to the dataset if you can check it please.

Comment: @Anas116 then you would need to handle that column separately

Comment: What would you suggest as an effective fuction to handle such a problem in a simple way ?

Comment: @Anas116 there isn't a simple function that can do this, because you seem to have arbitrary ordering of different numeric ranges that you would need to tell the function about. Do you have something like a look-up table of what the values mean and what their ordering should be?

Comment: I think the update answer will be ok with me so thank you o much